# tail.select javascript copy content of select to another select

Tags: javascript, html, tail.select

Im trying to copy the options of a select to another select input. Im currently using tail.select below solution is not working for me.

```
  document.getElementById("sama_sesuai_ktp").onclick = function() { copyAlamat() };

  function copyAlamat() {
    // GET THE OPTIONS OF THE SELECTS
    var sesuai_provinsi = document.getElementById('sesuai_fk_provinsi_value');
    var sesuai_kota = document.getElementById('sesuai_fk_kota_value');
    var sesuai_kecamatan = document.getElementById('sesuai_fk_kecamatan_value');
    var sesuai_kelurahan = document.getElementById('sesuai_fk_kelurahan_value');

    sesuai_provinsi_options = sesuai_provinsi.innerHTML;
    sesuai_kota_options = sesuai_kota.innerHTML;
    sesuai_kecamatan_options = sesuai_kecamatan.innerHTML;
    sesuai_kelurahan_options = sesuai_kelurahan.innerHTML;

    // FIND THE SELECTS THAT THE OPTIONS WILL BE COPIED
    var domisili_provinsi = document.getElementById('domisili_fk_provinsi_value');
    var domisili_kota = document.getElementById('domisili_fk_kota_value');
    var domisili_kecamatan = document.getElementById('domisili_fk_kecamatan_value');
    var domisili_kelurahan = document.getElementById('domisili_fk_kelurahan_value');

    // SET THE OPTIONS
    domisili_provinsi.innerHTML = sesuai_provinsi_options;
    domisili_kota.innerHTML = sesuai_kota_options;
    domisili_kecamatan.innerHTML = sesuai_kecamatan_options;
    domisili_kelurahan.innerHTML = sesuai_kelurahan_options;

  }
```

This is the sample HTML. THis is the first  select. The options is populated via ajax. And we will have a button that will get all the options from this to the second select which looks exactly same like this just different id

```
<div class="Mt(1rem)">
    <label for="" class="Mstart(1rem) Pb(8px) D(b) Fz(0.875rem)">Kota</label>
    <select data-kota class="cph Px(1rem) Py(0.8125rem) Bgc($input1) Bdrs(4px) Bxsh($c1):f O(n) Bd(n) D(b) W(100%) Maw(344px)" name="sesuai_fk_kota_value" id="sesuai_fk_kota_value" required>                                                
      <option selected disabled ></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the javascript where we initialize the tail.select

```
const kota = tail.select("[data-kota]", {
  search: true,    
  openAbove: false,
  placeholder : 'Please Choose Kota',
  hideDisabled: true
});
```

Comment: can you add your HTML markup to show what is what please?

Comment: Updated the codes. Included the HTML and initialization. Also added some points on how I need to do it.